# How to take advantage of Spark 2.0 "whole-stage code generation"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, compilation, apache-spark-sql

I have been reading many articles about Spark 2.0 "whole-stage code generation". Since the technique optimize the code at compiling stage, I have several questions about that:

Q1. Can Python or R take advantage of this technique?
 Q2. In Scala/Java, How to take advantage of this technique? Should I have to bring all the query using Spark's API, or just a string query is good enough? For example, can each of the following programs taking advantage of the "whole-stage code generation":

case 1:

```
sparksession.sql("select * from a john b on a.id = b.id")
```

case 2:

```
val talbe_a = sparksession.sql("select * from a)
val table_b = sparksession.sql("select * from b)
val table_c = table_a.join(table_b, table_a(COL_ADID) === table_b(COL_ADID))
```

Q3. If Q2 case 1 is able to utilize "whole-stage code generation", how about we read the query string from external files, like that:

```
val query = scala.io.Source.fromFile(queryfile).mkString
sparksession.sql(query)
```

In the above code, the complier really doesn't know what the query string looks like, at the compiling stage, can it utilize the "whole-stage code generation" technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All languages using Spark SQL API can benefit from codegen as long as they don't use language specific extensions (Python UDF, `dapply`, `gapply` in R)
2. Both SQL and `DataFrame` APIs are supported and they way you provide the query doesn't matter. Codegen is internal process applied between user input and query execution.